# no space between isset and htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

I have the following code in my header, it works, but I'm wondering if it can be optimized in any way.

```
<?php echo isset($page_title) ? strip_tags($page_title):""; echo htmlspecialchars("$website", ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

on the homepage, I don't have a $page_title set, and it's operating fine, with the exception when a $page_title is set on a page, it looks something like this "Change PasswordWebsite name", no space between Password and Website, if anyone could help that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate a space to `$page_title` when you print it.

```
<?php echo isset($page_title) ? (strip_tags($page_title) . " ") : "" ; echo htmlspecialchars($website, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

Comment: that works, thanks, with how long the code is, is it acceptable or can it be optimized? i just want to make sure i code to the best standards, thanks.

Comment: It seems fine to me.